# Color coding and legend labels in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, scale

I have data which I'd like to plot using `ggplot`'s `geom_point`:

```
  set.seed(1)
  df <- data.frame(x=rnorm(100),y=rnorm(100),val=c(rnorm(90),rep(NA,10)))
```

I add colors according to intervals of `df$val`:

```
  intervals.df <- data.frame(interval=c("(-3,-2]","(-2,-0.999]","(-0.999,0]","(0,1.96]","(1.96,3.91]","(3.91,5.87]","not expressed"),
                             start=c(-3,-2,-0.999,0,1.96,3.91,NA),end=c(-2,-0.999,0,1.96,3.91,5.87,NA),
                             col=c("#2f3b61","#436CE8","#E0E0FF","#7d4343","#C74747","#EBCCD6","#D3D3D3"),stringsAsFactors=F)
  df <- cbind(df,do.call(rbind,lapply(df$val,function(x){
    if(is.na(x)){
      return(data.frame(col=intervals.df$col[nrow(intervals.df)],interval=intervals.df$interval[nrow(intervals.df)]))
    } else{
      idx <- which(intervals.df$start <= x & intervals.df$end >= x)
      return(data.frame(col=intervals.df$col[idx],interval=intervals.df$interval[idx]))
    }
  })))
```

Here I set `df$col` as `factor` and set the labels to be the intervals so I can plot them in the legend:

```
  df$col <- factor(df$col,levels=intervals.df$col,labels=intervals.df$interval)
```

This will also display all the intervals including those that the `df$val` might not cover, but I want that.

And here's how I try to plot it:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df,aes(x=x,y=y,colour=col))+geom_point(cex=2,shape=1,stroke=1)+labs(x="X",y="Y")+theme_bw()+theme(legend.key=element_blank(),panel.border=element_blank(),strip.background=element_blank())+scale_shape(solid=T)+scale_fill_manual(drop=FALSE,values=levels(df$col),name="DE")
```

Which gets me close but the colors are not right:
[image]

So I thought this plot command will correct that (adding `scale_color_manual`):

```
ggplot(df,aes(x=x,y=y,colour=col))+geom_point(cex=2,shape=1,stroke=1)+labs(x="X",y="Y")+theme_bw()+theme(legend.key=element_blank(),panel.border=element_blank(),strip.background=element_blank())+scale_shape(solid=T)+scale_fill_manual(drop=FALSE,values=levels(df$col),name="DE")+scale_color_manual(drop=FALSE,values=levels(df$col),name="DE")
```

But that throws the error:

```
Error in grDevices::col2rgb(colour, TRUE) : invalid color name '(0,1.96]'
```

So, how to I get the colors right (and the legend `name` right too)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is map the colors to `interval` after setting the levels via `intervals.df` so the order of the levels and the number of levels is correct.  Use the colors from `intervals.df`, making a named vector of the colors to pass to `scale_color_manual`.

```
# Set levels of interval via intervals.df
df$interval = factor(df$interval, levels=intervals.df$interval)

# Named vector of the colors based on intervals.df
colors = intervals.df$col
names(colors) = intervals.df$interval

ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y, colour=interval))+
    geom_point(cex=2, shape=1, stroke=1) +
    labs(x="X", y="Y")+
    theme_bw()+
    theme(legend.key=element_blank(),
         panel.border=element_blank(), strip.background=element_blank())+
    scale_color_manual(values = colors, name = "DE", drop = FALSE)
```

Comment: How do you get this to have the legend include all intervals.df$col and intervals.df$interval and not just the ones included in df?

Comment: @dan See edit; you need `drop = FALSE` in `scale_color_manual`.